# JSON serialization (using Jquery plugin) w/ Struts2 interceptors -

Tags: json, struts2, interceptor

I'm trying to implement http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/SelectTag#A_simple_Doubleselect_with_Topics but I can't seem to combine the json interceptor with other interceptors successfully.

In my struts.xml:

```
<package name="admin" namespace="/admin" extends="struts-default,json-default">
    <action name="LoadLists" method="loadLists" class="test.JSONAction">
        <interceptor-ref name="json">
            <param name="contentType">application/json</param>
            <!--interceptor added to override this property below-->
            <param name="excludeNullProperties">true</param> 
        </interceptor-ref>
        <result name="success" type="json"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig"/>
    </action>
</package>
```

Here's some of the action class code.

Note that I need the `session` variable and therefore have added the `<interceptor-ref name="servletConfig"/>` line above to set the session variable so that it can be used in the following Java code:

```
public String loadLists() {
    items = (List<String>) session.get("itemsList");
    if (itemSelected.equals...
    // Do stuff to process the list and generate the second list...            
}

public void setItemSelected(String itemSelected) {
    this.itemSelected = itemSelected;
}
```

BUT when I have `<interceptor-ref name="servletConfig"/>`, error logs show:

```
org.apache.struts2.json.JSONInterceptor.debug:68 - Content type must be 'application/json' or 'application/json-rpc'. Ignoring request with content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

and the variable `itemSelected` never gets set because the json serialization is ignored!

If I remove `<interceptor-ref name="servletConfig"/>` then I can't access the session!

What am I missing?

Comment: Sorry, my bad.  I should have tested this more thoroughly.  What I thought was the problem really wasn't a problem at all.  Fixed by using default struts2 interceptors.  It leaves a lot of warnings in my error logs but I'll worry about that later.

Comment: This an observation but 'extends="struts-default,json-default"' is better written as: 'extends="json-default"' since if you look in your struts2-json-plugin-x.x.x.jar under the default package and open struts-plugin.xml you'll see that 'package name="json-default" extends="struts-default"' obviously not a big deal but worth knowing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here appears to be that you are not making an AJAX/JSON request to your action, you are posting to it using a standard form approach.

The message that you have provided is saying that the `Content-Type` *request* header was expected to be JSON-related, but instead was `x-www-form-urlencoded`. In other words, the request was not an AJAX/JSON request, but was just a normal form submit.

Double check how you are making the request to your `JSONAction` and make sure that you are actually sending the request properly.